# What is the meaning of metallic gate in graphene?

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, definition, graphene

While reading the paper: "Graphene bilayers with a twist"
I came across this sentence: "To carry out transport
or STS measurements, additional fabrication steps are necessary,
including depositing the stack on another hBN flake to complete
the encapsulation, and depositing **metallic gates** and contacts."
What are the metallic gates here exactly?
What is meant by gates?
PS: I really don't know what it even means so I would appreciate a simple explanation

Answer (score 1):

Gates are conducting stripes placed near, but not in electric contact with,  a  [two-dimensional electron gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_electron_gas) or other thin conducting layer (such as graphene). A  positive voltage applied to the gate attracts electrons in thegas   and a negative votage repels them. If the negative voltage is high enough the electrons cannot get though the barrier which becomes a "gate" controling the flow.  This is how [field effect transistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-effect_transistor) work. It's a bit like the "grid" in vacuum tubes

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful